# Initialization of values before constructor

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

**Problem:**
I implemented this new opeator for my class.

```
void* Objects::MemoryObject::operator new(size_t size, Memory::BaseAllocator* allocator) {
    Objects::MemoryObject* newObject = static_cast<Objects::MemoryObject*>(allocator->allocateItem(size));
    
    newObject->_objectAllocator = allocator;
    newObject->_objectSize      = size;

    return newObject;
}
```

It will allocate memory for object and set attributes for object size and allocator used in allocation. Problem is that these values will be removed by constructor (object size will be 0, pointer to allocator will be NULL) **even** if i don't initialize them in code. How to avoid this? Is there any way to tell compiler that these attributes are initialized before constructor ?

**What i tried**: I tried to use `volatile` qualifier but it doesn't work

Comment: Just curious, why did you think `volatile` has anything to do with that?

Comment: `newObject->_objectAllocator = allocator;` would be UB, as you have not yet constructed the object.

Comment: `operator new` is a memory allocation function. An object will be created in the memory it returns, so storing anything there is futile.

Comment: @molbdnilo i throught C++ ignore values that are not initialized by code in constructor

Comment: Uninitialized values are *indeterminate*; there is no telling what they will be.  The compiler and runtime are free to do whatever they like with the returned memory before the object is created.

Comment: Do you really need these during the object's lifetime, or is it just bookkeeping data for the benefit of `operator delete`?

Comment: @molbdnilo i need them during object lifetime

Comment: Well, you can't do it this way, so you need to think of something else. Why do you need them? I can't think of anything that might be interested in these except the deallocation. (Related: the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: @molbdnilo pointer to allocator is used in case that object needs to realocate something. This object (that contains this operator new) is parent of other objects. Other objects are adding stuff like arrays of pointers or tables and these can use same allocator as object itself.

Comment: That Memory::BaseAllocator is facade for managed heap . I implemented it like that for purposes of testing (using different allocator during testing and different one during release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that works is adding one structure that is holding informations. These informations are used later by constructor. This struct is defined in code file (.cpp) so it is invisible for other objects in program.

```
// Here we will save our values
struct {
    Memory::BaseAllocator*  allocator;
    Memory::SystemInt       size;
} MemoryObjectValues;

// we will take values from struct save them in attributes
Objects::MemoryObject::MemoryObject() {
    this->_objectAllocator  = MemoryObjectValues.allocator;
    this->_objectSize       = MemoryObjectValues.size;

    MemoryObjectValues.allocator    = nullptr;
    MemoryObjectValues.size         = 0;
}

// during allocation we will save values into struct 
void* Objects::MemoryObject::operator new(size_t size, Memory::BaseAllocator* allocator) {
    Objects::MemoryObject* newObject = static_cast<Objects::MemoryObject*>(allocator->allocateItem(size));
    // set important values like size and pointer to allocator
    MemoryObjectValues.allocator    = allocator;
    MemoryObjectValues.size         = size;
    
    return newObject;
}
```

Comment: Global usage makes it non-reentrant (and not thread safe).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you shouldn't use ordinal new for your task. Use something like "fabric": specific function, it allocates memory, creates instance and fills additional values.

Comment: Soo i must use factory method for this